# Sum column values in flipped table with generated column names

Tags: mysql

I have the following *MySQL-code*:

```
    select question, 
      sum(case when value = '1' then 1 else 0 end) '1',
      sum(case when value = '2' then 1 else 0 end) '2',
      sum(case when value = '3' then 1 else 0 end) '3',
      sum(case when value = '4' then 1 else 0 end) '4',
      sum(case when value = '5' then 1 else 0 end) '5',
      sum(case when value = '6' then 1 else 0 end) '6',
      sum(case when value = '7' then 1 else 0 end) '7',
      sum(case when value = '8' then 1 else 0 end) '8',
      sum(case when value = '9' then 1 else 0 end) '9',
      sum(case when value = '10' then 1 else 0 end) '10',
      count(value) AS total -- this line should be edited
    from
    (
        select answer1 value, 'answer1' question
        from questionaire
        union all
        select answer2 value, 'answer2' question
        from questionaire
        union all
        select answer3 value, 'answer3' question
        from questionaire
    ) src
    group by question
```

This is a `select` statement that flips a table formatted like this:

```
id   |  e-mail           | answer1 | answer2 | answer3
------------------------------------------------------
1    |  test@example.com |    1    |    6    |   8
2    |  test2@example.com|    1    |    1    |   7
3    |  test2@example.com|    1    |    1    |   0
```

The flipped table looks like this

```
question | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 | total
---------------------------------------------------------
answer 1 | 3 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0  |   3
answer 2 | 2 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0  |   3
answer 3 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0  |   3
```

There is a `total` column that counts all the values, however I want it to `sum` up all the values from columns before it. Because when somebody skips a questions it counts as a zero and the sum in total will be wrong (see the table, answer 3). The total is `3`, and should be `2`.

My question is how to sum up all the values from 1 to 10 within the total column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would write it instead as:

```
sum(value in ('1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10') )
```

Or, perhaps more simply as:

```
sum(value > '0')
```